# SQL Select Statement Limit & Desc Order

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, limit

Just need someone to tell me if this statement has the proper syntax or not; i cannot get it to work properly.

```
SELECT plantname, orderfreq, totalincome 
FROM plantreview 
WHERE score >='5' 
AND recommended='1' 
ORDER BY score DESC, LIMIT +0, 5
```

Comment: Syntax is good less the comma after `DESC`. What doesn't work?

Comment: @CAbbott My guess would be MySQL given the `LIMIT`

Comment: I agree are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it's MySQL; im new to using it all to be honest. So it should work minus the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MySQL, there should not be a `,` after the `ORDER BY` or `+` in the `LIMIT`. If your column is an integer, you also don't need to encase it in quotes.

```
SELECT plantname, orderfreq, totalincome 
FROM plantreview 
WHERE score >='5' 
AND recommended='1' 
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02da2/1)